# Why some images disapper in ListView when I pull up/down to refresh list

Tags: android

I have a trouble with image disappering in ListView when I pull up/down to refresh list. Only some images of certain user/users disappear when I refresh list(i.e. upload next 10 homelines). I use pull-to-refresh listview(from Chris Banes) and ImageLoader(from nostra13). I thought that there is priority problem and tried to manipulate thread priorities but it isn`t so. As I see there is a problem somewhere else. Could anybody explain me where is the problem and how to solve it?

ListView adapter:

```
public class TweetListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<Tweet> tweets;
    public ImageManager imageManager;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public TweetListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);

        this.context = context;
        this.tweets = tweets;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUrl(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();
//      imageManager = new ImageManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView username;
        public TextView message;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            // Set up Layout inflater to make custom view
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.customtweetlist, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
            holder.message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        // Get tweet position and attach each tweet to different custom view
        // blocks
        final Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
        if (tweet != null) {
            holder.username.setText(tweet.getToUser());
            holder.message.setText(tweet.getText());
            holder.image.setTag(tweet.getProfileImageUrl());

            File cacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "UniversalImageLoader/Cache");
            // ImageMnagaer is created for images caching
            //imageManager.displayImage(tweet.getProfileImageUrl(), context, holder.image);
            // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();
            // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration. Do it once.
            imageLoader.init(config);
            // Load and display image asynchronously
            imageLoader.displayImage(tweet.getProfileImageUrl(), holder.image, options);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you initialize the loader multiple times if your own comment says "Do it once"?

Comment: So, initialization is done only once. Firstly, I get Loader instance, next setup configuration, then Loader initialization with config and display image. I don`t see another loader initialization.

Comment: You initialize image loader each time `getView` gets called...

Comment: Ou, you are wright. That is quite strong mistake. I have moved config setup and initialization to tweetListAdapter class but no positive result. Some images are disappeared on refresh.